# error when building a GWT app after updating GWT

Tags: gwt, ant, build

after updating GWT2.0 to the GWT2.4, eclipse shows error message when building GWT app with ant.
 here is the message:

```
[java] Compiling module com.certus.noc.noc
 [java]    Validating newly compiled units
 [java]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/EX-GWT/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasDirectionalSafeHtml.java'
 [java]          [ERROR] Line 26: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.safehtml.client.HasSafeHtml; did you forget to inherit a required module?
 [java]          [ERROR] Line 33: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtml; did you forget to inherit a required module?
 [java]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/EX-GWT/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java'
 [java]          [ERROR] Line 27: No source code is available for type com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus; did you forget to inherit a required module?
 [java]          [ERROR] Line 32: Cannot cast from GwtEvent.Type<H> to Event.Type<H>
 [java]          [ERROR] Line 32: No source code is available for type com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.Event<H>.Type<H>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
 [java]          [ERROR] Line 36: No source code is available for type com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.HandlerRegistration; did you forget to inherit a required module?
 [java]          [ERROR] Line 42: Cannot cast from GwtEvent.Type<H> to Event.Type<H>
 [java]          [ERROR] Line 51: No source code is available for type com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.Event<H>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
 [java]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/EX-GWT/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DirectionalTextHelper.java'
 [java]          [ERROR] Line 32: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.HasDirectionEstimator; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

and the inherites module in gwt.xml file

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
<inherits name='com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT'/>
<inherits name='com.extjs.gxt.desktop.WebDesktop' />
<inherits name='com.certus.noc.resources.Resources' />
<!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
<!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
<!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
<inherits name='com.certus.noc.resources.Resources' />
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

<!-- Other module inherits                                      -->
<inherits name='com.extjs.gxt.themes.Themes' />

<inherits name='com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N' />
<inherits name='com.extjs.gxt.charts.Chart' />
```

Thanks in advance for any answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
<inherits name="com.google.web.bindery.event.Event"/>
```

to your main `<project>.gwt.xml` it should solve Events problems
Also try to place your gwt jars before gxt jars in your classpath

And check that `HasDirectionalSafeHtml` take `HasSafeHtml` and `SafeHtml` from `gwt-servlet-2.4.0.jar`, or event check if `gwt-servlet-2.4.0.jar` exists in your classpath.

This should solve `HasDirectionalSafeHtml` problems

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have try the mothed you told but there is still as the same. someone told me what the problem is related to the environment , i will try others.
and i found the similar Question.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

delete all the jars in the WEB-INF/lib, and then copy the new jar from APP Engine and other

userful . then it works